# Conditionally multiplying one col to another based on a category

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have two dataframes. Dataframe A looks like this

| Country | Volume |
| --- | --- |
| USA | 360 |
| MX | 240 |
| MX | 520 |

And dataframe B

| Country | Multiplier |
| --- | --- |
| USA | .5 |
| MX | .25 |

How can I apply the multiplier from df B to the corresponding country on df A?

At the moment, I haven't tried any particular approach because I am not sure how to start.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this:

```
to_dict = dict(zip(df_b['Country'],df_b['Multiplier'])) #{'USA': 0.5, 'MX': 0.25}
df_a['multiplier'] = df_a['Volume'] * df_a['Country'].map(to_dict)
```

**Output**:

```
    Country Volume  multiplier
0   USA     360     180.0
1   MX      240     60.0
2   MX      520     130
```